# How do you do some jQuery inside a ruby if/else loop in a Rails html.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a button which is always present in the html, but by default is hidden with the css `#comments_button{ display: none; }`.

I want the button to appear if the notice has any comments. In _notice.html.erb:

```
<%= button_tag "Comments", id: "comments_button" do %>
  <span>Comments</span>
<% end %>

<% if notice.comments.any? %>
  *** get jQuery to do $("#comments_button").show(); ***
<% end %>
```

How do you call the jQuery from inside the ruby if/else loop?

Please note, the button should always be present in the html so I can't do this:

```
<% if notice.comments.any? %>
  <%= button_tag "Comments", id: "comments_button" do %>
    <span>Comments</span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can insert `script` tag in erbs, e.g. following should work

```
<%= button_tag "Comments", id: "comments_button" do %>
  <span>Comments</span>
<% end %>

<% if notice.comments.any? %>
   <script>
      $("#comments_button").show();
   </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery at all? A far better solutions is do this with just HTML and CSS.

```
/* application.css */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Lets create a helper method which adds the hidden class conditionally:

```
module CommentsHelper
  def comments_button(comments, opts = {}, &block)
    opts[:id] ||= 'comments_button'
    opts.merge!(class: 'hidden') unless comments.any?
    if block_given?
      button_tag(opts, block)
    else 
      button_tag(content_tag(:span, 'Comments'), opts)
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= comments_button(notice.comments) %>
```

**Note**

You should remove this rule from your css:

```
#comments_button{ display: none; }
```